# What is the possessive form of course?

Tags: single-word-requests

I think the possessive form of `course` is `course's`, but it keeps appearing with a red squiggly underline in my Google Doc. Either the dictionary used by Google Docs is incomplete or I'm wrong. I'm thinking it's the latter.

So, **what is the possessive form of `course`**?

Comment: Course's is correct. Maybe there is something else wrong with the grammar of your sentence? Please edit your question to show the full sentence that you typed in the Google Doc.

Comment: Red squiggly line refers to a spelling error. Google Docs doesn't do grammar check from my understanding (even tested it with "we is going home" to confirm). Maybe this is a problem with Google's dictionary used in Docs.

Comment: Yes, it's an bug in Google Docs' dictionary. I tried it too. I get a red line in Google Docs, but not in MS Word. You should accept Cerberus's answer, I suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Course's* is indeed correct. All automated spelling correctors I've seen so far, including that of Microsoft Word, are not seldom wrong. Use them as tools and in the way they were intended: not as an authority, but as an indicator of the *possibility* that you may have made a typo.